# Knowledge Article Body Not Showing Up

Tags: knowledge, customer-community

We have a community cloud customer portal set up that we have Cases visible to the customer and during testing before launch, we have noticed that while attached articles after being displayed after being attached to Cases, customers who click on the articles can't see the body of the article.

Comment: You would like to check the field level security of article types fields .The field level security for portal users may not be set .

Comment: Nope, field level security is fine

Comment: Is article set to visible for the portal